# Biblatex adds comma before author in footnotes

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

The footnote should look like this[image]

But unfortunately it looks like this:
[image]

So, it adds an comma every time I use a prefix in \footcite

my preamble looks like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,article]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref} %anklickbares Inhaltsverzeichnis

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} %Silbentrennung deutsche Rechtschreibung
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Codierung
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{times} % Schriftart Times New Roman
\setkomafont{disposition}{\normalfont\bfseries} %Times New Roman überall
\renewcommand{\footnotesize}{\normalsize} %Fußnotengröße

\usepackage[backend=biber, sortcites = true, sorting=nty, style=apa]{biblatex}%zum Fußnote zitieren + Einstellungen wie Fußnote aussehen wird
\addbibresource{Literaturverzeichnis.bib}
\renewcommand{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\space} % : bei Literaturverzeichnis

\makeatletter 
\DeclareCiteCommand{\footcite}[\mkbibfootnote] 
  {\bibsentence 
   \usebibmacro{cite:init}% 
   \usebibmacro{prenote}} 
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}% 
   \usebibmacro{textcite}} 
  {} 
  {\ifbool{cbx:parens} 
    {\bibcloseparen\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}} 
    {}% 
   \usebibmacro{postnote}% 
   \usebibmacro{cite:post}} 
\DeclareDelimFormat[footcite]{finalnamedelim} 
  {\ifnum\value{liststop}>2 \finalandcomma\fi\addspace\&\space} 
\makeatother 

\begin{document}   

\newpage
\section{Einleitung}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

It keeps adding a coma\footcite[Vgl.][3\psq]{jhull} after the prefix of footcite

\newpage
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

so and my bib. is like:

```
@article{jhull,
    Author = {John C. Hull},
    Date-Added = {2018-11-11 11:56:27 +0100},
    Date-Modified = {2018-11-11 12:15:03 +0100},
    Title = {Optionen, Futures und andere Derivate},
    Volume = {8},
    Year = {2012}}
```

I don't know what's the mistake here. Could anyone please help me?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX!  Could you post a *full* compilable small code reproducing the problem?

Comment: hey, thanks for your answer. I edited the main post and added the bib. also.

Answer (score 4):

Using the `textcite` macro in `\footcite` can have some weird side-effects, this is one of them. It can be avoided by using `\printunit` instead of `\setunit` in the definition of the `prenote` bibmacro.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,article]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, sortcites = true, style=apa]{biblatex}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\renewcommand{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\space}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\footcite}[\mkbibfootnote]
  {\bibsentence
   \usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{textcite}}
  {}
  {\ifbool{cbx:parens}
    {\bibcloseparen\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
    {}%
   \usebibmacro{postnote}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:post}}

\renewbibmacro*{prenote}{%
  \iffieldundef{prenote}
    {}
    {\printfield{prenote}%
     \printunit{\prenotedelim}}}

\DeclareDelimFormat[footcite]{finalnamedelim}
  {\ifnum\value{liststop}>2 \finalandcomma\fi\addspace\&\space}

\begin{document}
It keeps adding a comma\footcite[Vgl.][3\psq]{sigfridsson} after the prefix of footcite

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: The footnote reads "Vgl. Sigfridsson & Ryde (1998), S. 3 f."]

Note that the `hyperref` package should usually be loaded last. Additionally, `sorting=nty` does not really work well for `style=apa` since the APA style is an author-year style, so one would expect the bibliography to be sorted by author and year and not by author and title.

---

Since you seem to customise `biblatex-apa` quite a bit, you may want to consider whether it might not be more appropriate to use a different style altogether. `biblatex-apa` was specifically designed to implement the requirements of the APA manual, so it can be quite hard to achieve certain customisations even if they 'should be easy'. That's why I usually recommend to start from one of the standard styles when more changes are expected.

Here is an example that implements a style similar to the status quo of your style using my `biblatex-ext` bundle.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,article]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[
  backend=biber, style=ext-authoryear, giveninits=true, uniquename=init,
  articlein=false, innamebeforetitle=true,
]{biblatex}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\DeclareInnerCiteDelims{footcite}{\bibopenparen}{\bibcloseparen}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\DeclareDelimFormat{finalnamedelim}
  {\ifnum\value{liststop}>2 \finalandcomma\fi\addspace\&\space}

\DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\DeclareDelimFormat{editortypedelim}{\addspace}
\DeclareFieldAlias{translatortype}{editortype}
\DeclareDelimAlias{translatortypedelim}{editortypedelim}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\addcolon\space}

\DeclareFieldFormat
  [article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]
  {title}{#1\isdot}

\renewcommand*{\intitlepunct}{\addspace}

\renewcommand*{\volnumdelim}{}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{volume}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{number}{\mkbibparens{#1}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\nocite{nussbaum,worman,geer,westfahl:space,gaonkar:in}
\begin{document}
Lorem\footcite[Vgl.][3\psq]{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks for your help. For some reason it keeps saying "! Undefined control sequence. \DeclareInnerCiteDelims" and "! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}." Even if I use your code in a new document.

Comment: @dolornow Do you get other errors as well (before that)? Are you using the newest version of `biblatex` (3.12 or 3.11) and `biblatex-ext` (0.5a)?

Comment: Wow, I just have to say: THANKS A LOT. You're the real goat. I hope your advices will improve my Latex knowledge since I just started using it. I really really appreciate your help.

Comment: @dolornow Baa-baa? Glad I could help.